# List of links to images in website with wget

Tags: wget, web

I have a question, as much as I think I cannot think of the way to put all links of pictures in **a list**, I asked this question before but it was marked as duplicate to post where OP asked to **download** all pictures.

I tried `wget -r -P /save/location -A jpeg,jpg http://www.domain.com` but it's only downloading to computer. How can I extract a list of  all images to a file?

Answer (score 3):

use spider option and pipe the output to grep to get only the links out of them

```
wget --spider --force-html -r -l2 "www.domain.com" 2>&1   | grep '^--' | awk '{ print $3 }'   | grep '\.\(jpeg\|jpg\)$'
```

this will display all the links to the standard output, you direct it to a file:

```
wget --spider --force-html -r -l2 "www.domain.com" 2>&1   | grep '^--' | awk '{ print $3 }'   | grep '\.\(jpeg\|jpg\)$'>links.txt
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but grep comand doesnt grep anythink even if u write letter 'grep a >links.txt'

Comment: whole terminal just stuck and nothing happens

Comment: just updated my answer with the right params